# Difference between the gdx-setup-ui and gradle setup tool?

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, setup-project

What is the big difference between the `gdx-setup-ui` and `gradle` setup tool in libgdx? I used both and did not get the difference between these two. Which one should I use? Why does libgdx recommend the gradle setup tool? What role plays the `gradle` folder when you create a project?

Comment: On the page for the `libgdx-old-setup-ui`: "This setup UI has been replaced by the new Gradle-based setup. This repository is meant for users that can not use the Gradle based setup for some reason."

Comment: Gradle manages your libraries and your build tasks. It enables you to use any IDE (not just Eclipse) and move your project between IDEs easily. It makes it way, way, way, way easier to update your libraries.